# jQuery sums up incorrect value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to sum up two values in jquery (values can be decimal and non-decimal values) but its returning incorrect value.

Here are the codes

```
<?php
$licence_cost_inr = 1290.058;
$converted_currency = 64.056;
?>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      var total = 0;
      var txt = '';
      var inr = '<?php echo $converted_currency; ?>';
      var costinr = '<?php echo $licence_cost_inr; ?>';
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
        txt += $(this).attr('data')+', ';
      });
      var convert = total*inr;
      var finalinrcost = convert+costinr;
      alert(finalinrcost);

      $("#costdisplay").html(total);
      $("#inrdisplay").html(finalinrcost);
      $("input[name=ap_amount]").val(total);
      $("input[name=payment]").val(total);
      $("input[name=amount]").val(total*inr+costinr);
      $("input[name=apc_2]").val(txt.slice(0,-2));
      $("input[name=custom]").val(txt.slice(0,-2));
      $("input[name=udf2]").val(txt.slice(0,-2));
    });
  });
```

Here `finalinrcost` returns incorrect value. Expected sum up value is for example `1350.67` but it returns something unexpected like `129.04341290.434`. I am not getting what the error is as I am simply trying to add the things up. Please help.

Comment: Remove the quotes from your PHP lines: `var inr = <?php echo $converted_currency; ?>;`. By quoting them JavaScript treats them as strings, not numbers.

Comment: `var convert = total*(+inr); var finalinrcost = convert+(+costinr);` would work as well if you felt like keeping those as strings for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one of the values you are using for your calculations is a `string`. For example:

```
'123' + 123 == '123123'
```

Comment: I'd say this answer could use a bit more context, though it isn't wrong. The variables `inr` and `costinr` are both wrapped in `'`, so they'll be treated as strings.

Comment: then I think simply removing the `'` is okay.. that did the job.. thanks for pointing out the integer and string concepts.. I totally missed it.. but will keep in mind now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this example. If you are getting string than you should convert in to `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var total = 0;
      var txt = '';
      var inr = '10';
      var costinr = '1290.058';
      total += 200;
      var convert = total*parseFloat(inr);
      var finalinrcost = convert+parseFloat(costinr);
      alert(finalinrcost);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```